# What does robots.txt file do in PHP project?

Tags: search-engine, robots.txt

What does robots.txt file do in PHP project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really PHP, see:

**[Introduction to "robots.txt"](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/robots.shtml)**

> "Robots.txt" is a regular text file
>   that through its name, has special
>   meaning to the majority of "honorable"
>   robots on the web. By defining a few
>   rules in this text file, you can
>   instruct robots to not crawl and index
>   certain files, directories within your
>   site, or at all. For example, you may
>   not want Google to crawl the /images
>   directory of your site, as it's both
>   meaningless to you and a waste of your
>   site's bandwidth. "Robots.txt" lets
>   you tell Google just that.

Answer (score 2):

robots.txt is related to search engines robots and not specific to PHP projects.
it contains instructions for robots that crawl you website such as which urls you dont want to be crawled by the search engines and so on.

see http://www.webconfs.com/what-is-robots-txt-article-12.php

Answer (score 2):

It is used to instruct webcrawlers like google and yahoo to crawl only parts of the page or not at all. See http://www.robotstxt.org for more information.

Answer (score 0):

robots.txt lives in the / of your website.

When a search engine bot finds your website it first requests the robots.txt to find out which URIs it CAN and CANNOT index.

This is to prevent (it's a CONVENTION, so robots CAN ignore it) certain parts of your website  from popping up in Google / Yahoo (for example your shoutbox...)

More info http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

Comment: -1 because it doesn't really allow or forbid robots to do anything.

It's equivalent to hanging a sign on your door with the words "robots should die" on your front door. This will of course have horrible repercussions once the robot revolution starts, but meh...